# Accessing a Sqlite DB from a Web Application using javascript?

Tags: javascript, sqlite

Can we access a PC's local Sqlite Storage from a web application through javascript code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to access the PC's local File System with Javascript.

You could try the new HTML5 feature, which includes a Storage Engine similar to SQLite:
http://www.webreference.com/authoring/languages/html/HTML5-Client-Side/